# Parallelize integrate in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, numerical-integration, integrate

I was wondering if it is possible and how to parallelize the integrate function in R to speed up numerical integration.

I write here a small example in case someone could help me.

```
b0=function(time){0.05*sin(0.1*time)+0.1}  
d0=0.14  
#Function to integrate
f0<-Vectorize(function(t,d0){b0(t)-d0},"t")

integrate(f0,lower=0,upper=1000,d0=d0)$value
```

This small example is very fast, but I have more complicated examples which are slower and I would like to make them faster.

Comment: Could you just split the regions you're integrating over and parallelize that?

Comment: If you can create a function that is actually vectorized instead of using a loop with mapply/Vectorize you'll get much better speed gains than with parallelization.

Comment: @Roland but my function is already vectorized. You mean that if I parallelize that vectorized function I won't gain any speed??

Comment: You might get a speedup from compiling your integrand function.

Comment: I think there is package RcppNumerical that is really fast for integration.

Answer (score 0):

The above comment by @Roland is spot on. But, the answer to your question 
   directly is:

```
library(parallel)
options(mc.cores = 2)
b0=function(time){0.05*sin(0.1*time)+0.1}  
d0=0.14  
#Function to integrate
f0<-Vectorize(function(t,d0){b0(t)-d0},"t")

ans <- mclapply(
  list(c(0, 500), c(500, 1000)),
  function(i){
    integrate(f0,lower=i[1],upper=i[2],d0=d0)$value
  }
)

Reduce("+", ans)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee this will speed things up since `integrate` uses adaptive quadrature. The computational intensity is determined by the complexity of the integrand, not the length of the interval.